# How to validate JSON object against the existing XXXValidator classes used for form validation?

Tags: json, validation, spring-boot

I have a Controller, an Entity, and a Validator for my project.

The controller looks vaguely like this:

```
@RequestMapping("foo")
@Controller
public class RequestMapper {
   @RequestMapping("jsonCreate")
   @ResponseBody
   public String createInfo(@Valid @ModelAttribute("node") String nodeJson)  throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
      Foo obj = new ObjectMapper().readValue(nodeJson, Foo.class);

      ///missing validation

      fooDao.save(obj);
    }
}



@Entity
public class Foo {
   @NotNull
   private String bar;

   ///getters, setters, constructors omitted
}


public class FooValidator {
    @NotEmpty(message = "Bar cannot be null")
    @Size(min = 2, message = "Bar must be a minimum of 2 characters long")
    private String bar;

    ////getters, setters and constructors omitted
}
```

So, when I am trying to call the createInfo method with the JSON:
{ "bar" : "a" }

I do not get any of the validation that I do in a form (not unexpected, but still a bug to get fixed).

Could someone point me to what needs to happen to get the FooValidator to properly examine the Foo object?

I tried putting this in FooValidator:

```
public<T> List<String> validate (T input) {
  List<String> errors = new ArrayList<>();

  Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> violations = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator().validate(input);
  if (violations.size() > 0) {
        for (ConstraintViolation<T> violation : violations) {
       errors.add(violation.getPropertyPath() + " " + violation.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

And then calling

```
new FooValidator().validate(foo);
```

but nothing happened in regards to being at least 2 characters long.

Answer (score 0):

You should put `FooValidator` after @Valid then use ModelMapper to convert `FooValidator` to `Foo`

```
@Autowired
ModelMapper modelMapper;

public String createInfo(@Valid @ModelAttribute("node") FooValidator fooValidator) {

    Foo foo = modelMapper.map(fooValidator, Foo.class)

    fooDao.save(foo);
}
```

Comment: This would not work since I am getting JSON strings in the example.  I am trying to get my JSON to have the same validation (if possible) that my objects get.  This function is a REST endpoint that outside people are to use to send JSON to create objects in my database.